# Tracking for profile not working after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, personalization, experience-profile, express-migration-tool

After migrating from `Sitecore 8.0 update 3` to `Sitecore 9 update 1` using Sitecore Express Migration Tool 3.1, I have completed:

- Rebuild search index
- Rebuild link databases
- Deploy marketing definitions

Profile is migrated to Sitecore 9 too but profile card and pattern card value always show `0` although raw value has value.

[image][image]

I tried updating the Profile Card value and save but it still shows a value of `0`.
I tried creating a new profile and that works fine.
The item is tracking with this profile can't select profile card although raw value still has value :

[image]
[image]

I don't see any reference item for this profile either. It should be using a lot of items on tracking field:

[image]

Any suggestion about this issues?

Comment: Anything in the logs? Can you compare your webroot to the vanilla Sitecore 9.0 Up 1 webroot. Are any Sitecore files or dlls different?

Comment: Can you set profile cars on vanilla Sitecore 9 and compare raw values with your migrated values. Can you also compare raw values between old site and upgraded one?

Comment: @ChrisAuer  I got some errors on log : 
9776 10:34:01 ERROR Evaluation of condition failed. Rule item ID: Unknown, condition item ID: {E00DB4F0-B206-4544-AD90-25D201CFB62C}
Exception: System.Exception
Message: The profile definition does not exist - Visitor Type
Source: Sitecore.Analytics
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Tracking.VisitProfiles.get_Item(String profileName)

Comment: In addition, Raw value had the same between all versions

Comment: Can you please navigate to https://[YOUR_SITE]/sitecore/admin/DbCleanup.aspx, select "master" and then "Rebuild Descendants" and press "Execute Cleanup" button. I think you have a ad profile or missing value.

Comment: Great. I have added the answer below for anyone else with the same issue.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue you have is that one or more of your profiles are corrupt. Either by renaming or deleting. Everything internal to Sitecore profiling works off of names, not profile keys item or pattern card item IDs.

The way to solve this is to clean up the names/items in the database. To do this navigate to https://[YOUR_SITE]/sitecore/admin/DbCleanup.aspx, select "master" and then "Rebuild Descendants" and press "Execute Cleanup" button. That will put everything back in line.

Comment: you are my saviour brother, spent days trying figure out why my profile wasnt updating and this fixed the issue....THANK YOU

Comment: Glad to help. I actually got this one from support when I had the same issue. I wish analytics ran off of IDs.

Comment: Good one. Had the same issue after upgrading to 9.3. Ran "rebuild Decendants" on the web DB and it worked.